# Difficult grouped report from database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

```
ID  |  Start of range | End of range
------------------------------------
ID1 |  Ok-000001      | Ok-000009
ID1 |  Ok-000010      | Ok-000014
ID1 |  Ok-000015      |
ID1 |  Ok-000016      | Ok-000018
ID1 |  Ok-000037      | Ok-000042
ID2 |  Ok-000043      | Ok-000045
ID2 |  Ok-000046      | Ok-000052
```

From the sample database records above, I would like to produce a report with the following format:

```
ID1 Ok-000001 - Ok-000018, Ok-000037 - Ok-000042
ID2 Ok-000043 - Ok-000052
```

In the actual database, there are 55,640 records with 1,559 unique IDs.

I'll take any and all guidance.  I know that I need to group by ID.  I know that I should ignore the "Ok-" and just work with the numeric values.  I don't know how to look at the "Start of range" in the *next* record to see if it's a continuation of the "End of range" in the current record.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: I'm using Access (2010)

Comment: As far as I know this is not going to be easy in `Ms-Access`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just impossible to do in Ms-access SQL and you have to rely on VBA

I had 20 minutes to waste so I did it for you...

With the following table named `TableSO`

```
ID  Start of range  End of range
ID1 Ok-000001       Ok-000009      
ID1 Ok-000010       Ok-000014      
ID1 Ok-000015                      
ID1 Ok-000016       Ok-000018      
ID1 Ok-000037       Ok-000042      
ID2 Ok-000043       Ok-000045      
ID2 Ok-000046       Ok-000052
```

The following sub generates the report you want

```vb
Public Sub TableSO_Treatment()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim strReport As String
    Dim strStart As String
    Dim strEnd As String
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim strCurrent As String
    Dim strPrev As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strPrevID As String
    Dim strPrevEnd As String
    Dim strLastStart As String

    Dim intPrev As Long

    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, [Start of range] as start, [End of range] as end FROM TableSO ORDER BY [Start of range]")

    'init before loop
    strLastStart = Trim(RST!start)
    strPrevID = Trim(RST!ID)
    strCurrent = Trim(RST!ID) & " " & strLastStart


    ' Loop on all records
    While Not RST.EOF

        ' Init loop  value
        strID = RST!ID
        strStart = Trim(NZ(RST!start,""))
        strEnd = Trim(NZ(RST!end,""))

        ' if End Range empty give it the Start range value
        If strEnd = "" Then strEnd = strStart

        ' Make numbers out of the ranges
        lngStart = Val(Replace(strStart, "Ok-", ""))
        lngEnd = Val(Replace(strEnd, "Ok-", ""))


        ' Test if it's a new ID
        If strID <> strPrevID Then

            ' Its another ID !!!

            ' write new line
            strReport = strReport & strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd & vbCrLf

            'reinit curent line
            strCurrent = strID & " " & strStart
            strLastStart = strStart

        End If


        ' Test if we are in a streak of ranges
        If (lngprev + 1) = lngStart Then

            ' We are in a streak, do nothing

        Else

            ' The streak is broken, write current streak and init a new streak
            strCurrent = strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd & ", " & strStart

            'reinit the start range
            strLastStart = strStart

        End If

        ' Saving previous values for the next loop
        lngprev = lngEnd
        strPrevEnd = strEnd
        strPrevID = strID


        RST.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Last write
    strReport = strReport & strCurrent & " - " & strEnd & vbCrLf

    ' Et voila :)
    Debug.Print strReport
End Sub
```

StrReport contains :

> ```
> ID1 Ok-000001 - Ok-000018, Ok-000037 - Ok-000042
> ID2 Ok-000043 - Ok-000052
> ```

Note that this works perfectly with the sample of data you provided. If you have shown all possibilities it will work with all of your table.
But you might have forgot to specify some special cases and you'll have to adapt the procedure accordingly to match them. I have commented all the code properly so you can understand it and fix it by yourself if needed.

This is the only way to go. You will never achieve such a report with a Query and VBA is there for that

---

**Edit**

In this state the report will just be saved in memory and printed in the debug window. That's not optimal.

A first quick thing you can do is to :

1. create a form
2. add a very large textbox to it, name it `TextReport`.
3. add a button, and add the procedure code in it's click event.
4. at the end of the procedure, add an instruction `TextReport.Value = strReport`

Still it is not optimal if you have a very large table. Another possibility is to output the results into a text file :

1. In the VBA window, under tools/references, check the library "*Microsoft Scripting Runtime*"
2. Adapt the procedure like this and it will output the report to C:/AccessReport.txt

   Public Sub TableSO_Treatment()

   ```
   Dim RST As Recordset
   Dim strReport As String
   Dim strStart As String
   Dim strEnd As String
   Dim lngStart As Long
   Dim lngEnd As Long
   Dim strCurrent As String
   Dim strPrev As String
   Dim strID As String
   Dim strPrevID As String
   Dim strPrevEnd As String
   Dim strLastStart As String
   Dim intPrev As Long

   ' variables to output to a file :
   Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Dim objFile As Scripting.TextStream
   Const fsoForWriting = 2
   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\AccessReport.txt", fsoForWriting, True)


   Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, [Start of range] as start, [End of range] as end FROM TableSO ORDER BY [Start of range]")

   'init before loop
   strLastStart = Trim(RST!start)
   strPrevID = Trim(RST!ID)
   strCurrent = Trim(RST!ID) & " " & strLastStart


   ' Loop on all records
   While Not RST.EOF

       ' Init loop  value
       strID = RST!ID
       strStart = Trim(Nz(RST!start, ""))
       strEnd = Trim(Nz(RST!End, ""))

       ' if End Range empty give it the Start range value
       If strEnd = "" Then strEnd = strStart

       ' Make numbers out of the ranges
       lngStart = Val(Replace(strStart, "Ok-", ""))
       lngEnd = Val(Replace(strEnd, "Ok-", ""))


       ' Test if it's a new ID
       If strID <> strPrevID Then

           ' Its another ID !!!

           ' write new line
           strReport = strReport & strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd & vbCrLf
           objFile.WriteLine strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd

           'reinit curent line
           strCurrent = strID & " " & strStart
           strLastStart = strStart

       End If


       ' Test if we are in a streak of ranges
       If (lngprev + 1) = lngStart Then

           ' We are in a streak, do nothing

       Else

           ' The streak is broken, write current streak and init a new streak
           strCurrent = strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd & ", " & strStart

           'reinit the start range
           strLastStart = strStart

       End If

       ' Saving previous values for the next loop
       lngprev = lngEnd
       strPrevEnd = strEnd
       strPrevID = strID


       RST.MoveNext
   Wend

   ' Last write
   strReport = strReport & strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd & vbCrLf
   objFile.WriteLine strCurrent & " - " & strPrevEnd


   ' Et voila :)
   Debug.Print strReport
   objFile.Close
   Set objFile = Nothing
   Set objFSO = Nothing
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: Seems like SO is a code writing service after all. :) But yeah, some questions are just intriguing enough.

Comment: Thomas G, you're amazing.  After I test it against my data, I'll comment here again.

Comment: Needless to say, Thomas G, you're way, way ahead of me.

Comment: Needless to say, Thomas G, you're way, way ahead of me.  I understand your code, but I've never implemented a subroutine such as you've written.  Here's how I implemented it...I created a blank report, went into Design View, clicked the code button, inserted your subroutine into the report's module, changed the name of the table in the OpenRecordset statement, saved, created an Open event that calls your subroutine.  When I run the report, a run-time error '94' "Invalid use of Null" occurs on the statement "strEnd = Trim(RST!end)".  Probably one of those special cases you warned me about. :-)

Comment: @JWB This happens because your empty [end range] contains a NULL value and not a blank string as I expected. You have to change that instruction to `Trim(NZ(RST!end,""))` to change the nulls to a blank string. I adapt my procedure.

Comment: I also added instructions to get the results in a better format ;)

Comment: Final thanks to Thomas G.  I tested both the "to file" version and the "to textbox" version.  Because I have lots of records, I prefer the "to file" version.  Your hard work is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: @JWB glad to have helped  but don't forget your duties on stackoverflow: if I answered your question, mark the answer as accepted.  And upvote if you found the answer good. ;)